# Azure python Runbook fails running in portal but same code succeeds from dev box

Tags: python, azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Hi I am facing a strange problem. I have created a Azure python runbook under Azure automation account. For now the code is attempting to connect to a storage account and fetch all the containers.

Here is the code

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

cred = r"?sas-token-xyz-xyz"
source_container_name = "sample"
account_url = "https://xyzxyzxyz.blob.core.windows.net"

blob_source_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=cred)
containers_list = blob_source_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)

for container in containers_list:
    print(container)

print("Done")
```

This code when executed from my dev box gives proper results like below

```
$ python blob_runbook.py
{'name': 'sample', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 1, 20, 23, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'lease': {'status': 'unlocked', 'state': 'available', 'duration': None}, 'public_access': None, 'has_immutability_policy': False, 'deleted': None, 'version': None, 'has_legal_hold': False, 'metadata': {}}
Done
```

When it is executed from the **azure portal** I get the following error. Not able to comprehend

```
Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\xqnsssxx.aun\daad1b3f-94be-4ea4-b4ef-6730a3282b53", line 10, in <module>    for container in containers_list:  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 122, in __next__    return next(self._page_iterator)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 74, in __next__    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_models.py", line 399, in _get_next_cb    use_location=self.location_mode)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_generated\operations\_service_operations.py", line 341, in list_containers_segment    deserialized = self._deserialize('ListContainersSegmentResponse', response)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\msrest\serialization.py", line 988, in __call__    raise_with_traceback(DeserializationError, msg, err)  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\msrest\exceptions.py", line 50, in raise_with_traceback    raise errormsrest.exceptions.DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'RequestsTransportResponse' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Looking out for some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for accessing the blobs in the container by getting access to the storage account class.

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.storage import CloudStorageAccount
from azure.storage.blob.models import ContentSettings, PublicAccess


##Read data from storage account
sas = r"?sas-token-xyz-xyz"
account =  CloudStorageAccount(account_name='bunprdmelaasdata',sas_token=sas);
blobClient = account.create_block_blob_service()
containers = blobClient.list_containers();
for container in containers:
    print('Container Name: ' + container.name)

print("Done")
```

The only reason i can think of the `BlobServiceClient` was not available and i had to download and add to the automation python packager. But for the above I didn't add any python packages.